How to Mock data to pass AT in fitnesse
I have requirement to pass AT  to mock some data to pass.
In actual implementation it's taking current data and time
But I need to convert in to Julian date format
I don't know how to mock the data,I can't find references also.

To get an answer I believe you'll have to be more specific. What does your test setup look like, what fixtures and test system are you using? Do you have an example test page where you would like to generate/input the mock data?
